# Who has done what during the course of visiting wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, hacking

I run a small wordpress site.
I use Korean.
Today my statistics shows like the below.
[image: Hits for tody]

My blog has no more than 100 posts so I am suspicious about the 100+ hits from the same ip.

Can this be an evidence that Russians are trying to hack into my site?

Can there be any convenient way so that I know who's doing what with my posts? Something like someone from ip addr xx.xx.xx.xx entered at url:xxxx, jumped to url:xxxx, wrote a comment, jumped to xxxx, etc.

Comment: well.. welcoming to the internet with full of bots and scripts. ;) do you know that this what you request is tracking? Did you checked the server logs?

Comment: on my server, something like `lastb | grep 5.188.211.26` shows nothing. So I guess the suspicious ip is not trying to log into the server. Anyway `lastb` shows that there have be several attempts to log in from the same ip. This is another question if there is any way to block several attempts from the same ip. I might better look around first.